# About Britsh English pronunciation of a glottal stop

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

Is it a rule to use a glottal stop? Otherwise is it just optional?

Comment: In words like "butter"? Definitely not compulsory. Out of interest, why do you think it might be a rule? Unless your teacher has a strong regional accent I wouldn't expect a glottal stop there.

Comment: Words like "uh-oh" and "uh-uh" (meaning "no") always have glottal stops, so they're required. With almost every other word, there's a way to pronounce it without a glottal stop.

Comment: What words are you thinking of? Please edit your question to include more context

Comment: @gotube Not specific, but I wanted to know some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a glottal stop to replace /t/ is increasingly common in British English. There are many dialects of British English and most of them use glottal stops instead of /t/ in certain positions. There are no rules as far as I'm aware, but some accents (e.g. Cockney) use a glottal stop to replace /t/ in many different positions for example intervocalic (between vowels) t's as in *water, butter, better* etc., syllable-final and word-final t's as in *batman, hit, pitfall* etc. Some other accents use it only to replace word-final/syllable-final and pre-consonantal t's (*cut, pitfall, batman*). Word-initial /t/ is never pronounced as a glottal stop. Oh, and some people also use it before a syllabic n as in *button*.

Some dialects don't use glottal stops and in careful speech, it's certainly not  necessary to use it. Most accents use it only pre-consonantally (before another consonant), however.

Incidentally, there are also dialects that use it before word/syllable final *p, t, k*.